# How to make process substitution work from .screenrc?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

From .screenrc, I want to open a window with bash on directory /myDir.  Running `chdir /myDir` before runnning `screen` does not work for me because `.bashrc` has a line changing the working directory to a different one.

Therefore, I need a way to tell bash to cd into /myDir after .bashrc has run.  I can do this successfully from bash's command line:

```
bash --init-file <(echo "source .bashrc; cd /myDir")
```

However, when I do it from .screenrc:

```
screen -t bash bash --init-file <(echo "source .bashrc; cd /myDir")
```

the window fails to open.  Some error occurs that is never printed out.

Any shell magic to make it work?

Comment: Try (untested) `screen -t bash bash -c 'exec bash --init-file <(...)'`

Comment: I guess that's because screen is using `/bin/sh -c` to run that command, and `/bin/sh` doesn't support process substitutions.

Comment: @ktzap, no, that's because `<(...)` is a pipe. But that pipe is between the calling shell and the screen client, the process that the screen server will start to run that `bash --init-file`  won't see (won't have a fd on) that pipe.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas -EPARSE, sorry ;-) Digging deeper, it seems that `screen` is not even using `/bin/sh -c`, but it's splitting and parsing itself the command line, in the same way as gnome-terminal. Try with a command like `<ctrl-A>:screen cat | cat`

Comment: @ktzap, in a `screen X <(Y)` bash command line, `screen` doesn't have to split anything. The calling shell invokes `screen` with `X` and `/dev/fd/n` as separate arguments and with the fd n of the process it runs screen in open on a pipe. `screen` then connects to the screen server for the screen session (starts a new one if need be) and tells it to run `X /dev/fd/n` in a new process. But that screen server will not have access to that fd n.

Comment: What version of screen is that? Stracing the 4.06.02 I have here I got this: `execve("/usr/bin/echo", ["echo", "<(true)"], ... etc`. Notice that the Q is about the screen's internal `screen` command, the OP is talking about adding it to `~/.screenrc`.

Comment: I'm on version 4.08.00 (GNU).

Comment: @ktzap Anyhow, your solution with 'exec bash..." does the trick.  If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.  Thank you so very much!